# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound when using a module installed from a bdist_rpm

Tags: python, python-2.7, rpm, setuptools

I am trying to create a rpm of a CLI tool I have built. The rpm is being created and is installing without errors. However, when I try to use the CLI I get the following exception:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/bin/my_project", line 5, in <module>
            from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3141, in <module>
            @_call_aside
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3127, in _call_aside
            f(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3154, in _initialize_master_working_set
            working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 640, in _build_master
            ws.require(__requires__)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 941, in require
            needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 828, in resolve
            raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
        pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'my-project==0.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I tried to create a bare bones application with just following files to get it to work but I still get the same exception

`project/setup.py`

```
import sys

def main(args=None):
     print("Do Something")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then `project/my_project/__main__.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_project',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=['my_project'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_project = my_project.__main__:main'
        ]
     },
)
```

I am creating the rpm with the command `python setup.py bdist_rpm`

**EDIT**

The reason is my_project is being installed to usr/local/lib instead of /usr/lib. How can I change the default path?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but perhaps you can try using the `--prefix` option. E.g. `rpm -i --prefix /tmp/test my.rpm` as described [here](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-install-additional-options.html)

Comment: Suspect copy>>paste error. It looks like the contents of `setup.py` and `__main__.py` in post are reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually just specified a custom install script using the --install-script flag that used the prefix option for setup.py install

Contents of install-script:
`python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed -O1 --root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT --record=INSTALLED_FILES --prefix /usr`