# Troubleshooting pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound error

Tags: python, setup.py

Why does [this simple program](https://github.com/maphew/scraps/tree/master/bug-dist-not-found) result in a `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound` error when run and how do we fix it?

```
#setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_project',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=['my_project'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_project = my_project.__main__:main'
        ]
     },
)
```

.

```
##my_project/__main__.py

import sys

def main(args=None):
     print("Do Something")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Build:** `python setup.py install --root=target --prefix=usr`
**Run:** `.\target\usr\Scripts\my_project.exe`

#### Result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code-maphew\scraps\bug-dist-not-found\target\usr\Scripts\my_project-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3105, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3089, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3118, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 578, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 895, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'my-project==0.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

This Q is similar to [pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound when using a module installed from a bdist_rpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457144/pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-when-using-a-module-installed-from-a-bdist-rp), but not building an RPM. In that Q using `--prefix` solved the problem. That hasn't worked for me. I've replicated the same problem on Windows 10, Linux Mint, and Debian.

Full code in a repo here: https://github.com/maphew/scraps/tree/master/bug-dist-not-found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this same issue. The trouble is the code works on one computer but not on another. Also I am using a wheel that I built. Anyway, the solution I found was to upgrade pip and my package. eg

```
pip install --upgrade pip path/to/my_package
```

That re-installed both pip and my package, then the entry points were working.

Comment: This is causing my problem with pip Version 23.0.1 instead of fixing it

Comment: @WolfgangFahl It's hard to say.  First thing I would suggest is to include setuptools when you upgrade. Also, did you check the other answer? Maybe you have a misnamed requirement. If those don't work, you might want to try a new question with your specific example.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have similar issue mentioned in the question you also might have a name mismatch like I had:

setup.py

```
#setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_project',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=['my_project'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_project = my_project.__main__:main'
        ]
     },
    install_requires=[
        'req.lib',  # correct name req-lib
    ]
)
```

Interestingly in my case `pip install -e .` did not complain about the the error, but I got an error during execution, like the following one:

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'req.lib' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Importing was not a problem there the naming was correct the following ways:

```py
import req.lib
```

The package in my case was 'azure-identity' :)

The installation using *pip* has certainly different tolerance compared to *pkg_resources*.