# Invalid syntax with installed package python

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I have installed a package named 'Spexxy' with `python3 setup.py install` which worked fine.

Now, I am trying to use it, so with `ipython3` I import the package as follow `import spexxy` which also works fine, but when I try to use the different tools available in this package, I keep getting the error `invalid syntax` while I am following the documentation of the package, for example:

I want to creat a grid as specified in the documentation, using `spexxytools grid create`, here is what I do:
`spexxytools grid create --from-filename "lte(?P<Teff>\d{5})-(?P<logg>\d\.\d\d)(?P<FeH>[+-]\d\.\d)(\.Alpha=(?P<Alpha>[+-]\d\.\d\d))?\.PHOENIX"`

I get the error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-17-e08367969322>", line 1
    spexxytools grid create --from-filename "lte(?P<Teff>\d{5})-(?P<logg>\d\.\d\d)(?P<FeH>[+-]\d\.\d)(\.Alpha=(?P<Alpha>[+-]\d\.\d\d))?\.PHOENIX" .
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The documentation is present here: https://spexxy.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/

Can you tell me why ? Thanks

Comment: Please post the entire traceback of the error you get.

Comment: Yes it is, and I am trying to use it like them, or any other command in the documentation actually but nothing seems to work, and I wonder what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

That's shell syntax. Call it from IPython by prepending an exclamation mark:

```
!spexxytools grid create --from-filename ...
```

Based on [the documentation](https://spexxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/grid.html), the output will be a file called `grid.csv`.

If you actually want to use spexxy's Python API, see the [API Reference](https://spexxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html)

Comment: Using the exclamation mark i get the error: ```pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'spexxy==2.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application```

Comment: @Geo573 Seems to be an unrelated issue, but you might find a solution here: [Troubleshooting pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52375693/4518341)

Comment: Honnestly I am really l am really lost here and can not understand what is going wrong, could you help and explain to me please ?

Comment: @Geo573 About the `DistributionNotFound` error? I don't really know myself, sorry. You could ask a new question.