# Issue with pipenev and pip after installation of the package : pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I'm trying to install a package via `pip` and in an virtual environment using

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

then I install the package via pip

```
pip install <package name>
```

I get no error while installing it, but when I try to run the package with

```
<package name> --version
```

```
.
.
.
.
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'lockfile>=0.9; extra == "filecache"' distribution was not found and is required by CacheControl
```

Can anyone suggest how to debug this issue?

Comment: In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375693/troubleshooting-pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-error) there is a similar problem. I don't know if it could be useful for you